Apply Isolation forest on a grouped data in spark scala
I have a dataset like :

I want to group the data by Col1, Col2, Col3 and would like to apply isolation forest on that group by result. I am able to apply isolation forest if col3 value is just single value. I would like to apply Isolation Forest to the group based on groupBy values.
I am using Scala Spark for this.
Could you please help me with this.
Thanks, PML
I am able to apply isolation forest if col3 value is just single value. I would like to apply Isolation Forest to the group based on groupBy values.

`:require isolation-forest_3.5.0_2.13-3.0.5.jar

import com.linkedin.relevance.isolationforest._

val data = spark.read.option("header", "true").option("inferschema","true").csv("D:\\data.csv")

val groupedData = data.groupBy("col1","col2","col3").agg(collect_list("Values").as("Values"))

def processList(arr: Seq[Double]): Seq[Double] = {
    val rows = arr.map(d => Row(d))
    val schema = StructType(Seq(StructField("vector", DoubleType, nullable = false)))
    val df = spark.createDataFrame(spark.sparkContext.parallelize(rows), schema)
    val assembler = new VectorAssembler().setInputCols(Array("vector")).setOutputCol("features")
    val featureDF = assembler.transform(df)
    val isolation_forest = new IsolationForest().setMaxSamples(53).setMaxFeatures(1).setPredictionCol("predicted_label").setFeaturesCol("features").setScoreCol("outlier_score").setContamination(0.1)
    val model = isolation_forest.fit(featureDF)
    val features_scores_df = model.transform(featureDF)
    val scoresList = features_scores_df.select("outlier_score").as[Double].collect().toSeq
    scoresList
}

val processListUDF: UserDefinedFunction = udf(processList _)

val resultDF = groupedData.withColumn("processed_values", processListUDF($"Values"))

resultDF.show()

this is my code. it throws error if I try to show resultDF content.
error is as follows:
org.apache.spark.SparkException: [FAILED_EXECUTE_UDF] Failed to execute user defined function (`$read$$iw$$Lambda$5154/1868469734`: (array<double>) => array<double>).
        at org.apache.spark.sql.errors.QueryExecutionErrors$.failedExecuteUserDefinedFunctionError(QueryExecutionErrors.scala:198)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.errors.QueryExecutionErrors.failedExecuteUserDefinedFunctionError(QueryExecutionErrors.scala)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage3.processNext(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenEvaluatorFactory$WholeStageCodegenPartitionEvaluator$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenEvaluatorFactory.scala:43)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.$anonfun$getByteArrayRdd$1(SparkPlan.scala:388)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$2(RDD.scala:893)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$2$adapted(RDD.scala:893)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:367)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:331)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:93)
        at org.apache.spark.TaskContext.runTaskWithListeners(TaskContext.scala:166)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:141)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$4(Executor.scala:620)
        at org.apache.spark.util.SparkErrorUtils.tryWithSafeFinally(SparkErrorUtils.scala:64)
        at org.apache.spark.util.SparkErrorUtils.tryWithSafeFinally$(SparkErrorUtils.scala:61)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:94)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:623)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at $line78.$read$$iw.processList(<console>:4)
        at $line96.$read$$iw.$anonfun$processListUDF$1(<console>:1)
        ... 20 more


processList is udf, it is run on spark exectutors. You should not use spark dependencies in it like you do (spark.createDataFrame), it will not work because of spark architecture. Spark context can be accessed only on spark driver (main program).
